# Changing element text isn't working

Tags: javascript, html, window.open

It always seems to be a problem and I fail to see why, I'm trying to change element `p` text by using his ID, element `p id="para1"` is inside `PostEditor.html`:

The elementID I want to change is `para1` in the `following html`:

```
     <!DOCTYPE html>
     <html>
     <head>
           <title>Editor</title>
           <link href="styles/editor.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" />
           <script src="scripts/mainScript.js"> </script>
     </head>
     <body>
           <!-- Input fields -->
           <div class="center">
           <form id=caller  method="post">
                    <p id="para1" class="text"><Strong>Post your message</Strong></p>
                    <textarea id="textEditor" rows="16" cols="34" name="content"></textarea>
           <input type="submit" onclick="urlLoader('caller','posthandler.php')" value="Post">
           </form>
           </div>
          <!-- end Input fields -->

      </body>
      </html>
```

The following function is issued by a click on a link inside index.html and displaying the page you are seeing above and is then supposed to change its content:
From index.html I issue the function from link:

```
<a onclick="postEditing()"> Edit</a>
```

This line issue the following function:

```
function postEditing()
{
    var result =  window.open('PostEditor.html', 'newwindow', 'width=350,' + 'height=350');
    result.document.getElementById("para1").innerHTML = "11111111111";
    result.document.getElementById("para1").innerText = "11111111111";
    result.document.getElementById("para1").value = "11111111111";
}
```

As you can see I tried three methods. I'd never understand what is the difference between them, but I tried all three and none worked!

Comment: I'm not sure to understand... are you trying to update an HTML content of the PostEditor.html page from the index.html page, which just opened the PostEditor.html in a new window ?

Comment: It's working for me: [jsbin](http://jsbin.com/oqezot/1/edit)

Comment: postEditing is called from index.html

Comment: Well I tried that also without element ID. it doesn't matter look my code updates above I still have the same problem. Actually it's quite easy to build a similar code like mine and test it to see it is not working. I also ran debug on script and I find it very strange that I get errors on the innerHTML,innerText and Value lines :"Uncaught TypeError: cannot set the property 'innerHTML' of null "

Comment: @AlonMelanker see the **TESTED** solution in my answer: you have to wrap the code in an handler and execute it at **onLoad**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's because you're searching the document of the window which shows the index.html, not the document of the newly opened window. try following:

```
    ...
    var editorWindow = window.open('PostEditor.html', 'newwindow', 'width=350,' + 'height=350');
    editorWindow.document.getElementById("para1").innerHTML = "11111111111";
    ...
```

---

**EDIT:**
NOW i see the problem: in the function you're trying to access a property of the parameter `element`, but you don't pass a value for it. So this will end in an error because the accessed object is `undefinded`!

So you have three options to get it working:

1. test the parameter (always a good idea): `var ID = null; if(element) ID = element.id;`
2. pass a value: `<a onclick="postEditing(this)"> Edit</a>`
3. remove the line `var ID = element.id;`

---

**SOLUTION**: (TESTED)
I could not really say why, but the `index.html` found the `para1` and can successfully set the new text. But somehow the new window will reinitialize the old value again.

So you have to do the changing in an handler you run at `onLoad`:

index.html:

```
<html>
<head>
<script>
function postEditing() {
    var result =  window.open('PostEditor.html', 'newwindow', 'width=350,' + 'height=350');
    result.onload = function() {
        result.document.getElementById("para1").innerHTML = "11111111111";
    }
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<a onclick="postEditing()"> Edit</a>
</body>
</html>
```

PostEditor.html:

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
 <head>
       <title>Editor</title>
       <link href="styles/editor.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" />
       <script src="scripts/mainScript.js"> </script>
 </head>
 <body>
       <!-- Input fields -->
       <div class="center">
       <form id=caller  method="post">
                <p id="para1" class="text"><Strong>Post your message</Strong></p>
                <textarea id="textEditor" rows="16" cols="34" name="content"></textarea>
       <input type="submit" onclick="urlLoader('caller','posthandler.php')" value="Post">
       </form>
       </div>
      <!-- end Input fields -->

  </body>
  </html>
```

Comment: Beat me by a few seconds. Nevertheless: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_open.asp for reference.

Comment: then try one of the other properties (innerText / value). Since working with jQuery I've forgot how to do it without it ;)

Answer (score 2):

I'm fairly sure you will need to query the return result of calling window.open like this:

```
function postEditing(element)
{
    var ID = element.id;
    var result = window.open('PostEditor.html', 'newwindow', 'width=350,' + 'height=350');
    result.getElementById("para1").innerHTML = "11111111111";
    result.getElementById("para1").innerText = "11111111111";
    result.getElementById("para1").value = "11111111111";
}
```

[Untested though]

Answer (score 0):

Your button type is submit, which is posting the form.  The object is changing in the DOM, only after the script runs, the DOM is reloaded back to it's original state.  Try changing your button type to "button", and you should see the P element change appropriately.

---

Edit: Here's the HTML I used to determine the above.  Keeping the button as "submit" caused me to see the text change and then swap back.  The HTML below should keep the text in place.  HTH!

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
 <head>
       <title>Editor</title>

       <script>
       function postEditing(element)
   {

       document.getElementById('para1').innerHTML = "asdafs";

    }
       </script>
 </head>
 <body>
       <!-- Input fields -->
       <div class="center">
       <form id=caller  method="post">
                <p id="para1" class="text"><Strong>Post your message</Strong></p>
                <textarea id="textEditor" rows="16" cols="34" name="content"></textarea>
       <input type="button" onclick="postEditing('caller')" value="Post">
       </form>
       </div>
      <!-- end Input fields -->

  </body>
  </html>
```

Comment: I did that all I see is the page displaying for 0.1 msec 1111111111 and then the original title is jumping back

Comment: I removed the submit the form the input and everything left only  left only para1 and it's still not working :(

Comment: Just curious, have you used debugging tools (F12 on IE\Chrome, or Firebug in FireFox) and explored the para1 object.  Is it "found" in your GetElementById, and when stepping through the script, do you see the property get set?

Comment: I looked in the element and it didnt get set.

Comment: So GetElementById is finding the object?

Comment: Can you give me a name of one debugger that runs on scripts? The only debugger I got can debug only php

Comment: The most popular browsers all have built in script debugging.  Heres a tutorial for IE (http://www.htmlgoodies.com/html5/tutorials/script-debugging-using-the-internet-explorer-developer-tools.html#fbid=Zhuswhg6y7s), Chrome (https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/javascript-debugging) and FireFox(http://getfirebug.com/javascript).  Read a tutorial or 2, but its really simple to set these up to "step through" your script, identify your objects, and determine if the DOM object was found\manipulated in your script.

Comment: Well each time I reach the line result.document.getElementById("test").innerHTML="dsdssd"; I get the Uncaught TypeError: cannot set the property 'innerHTML' of null

Comment: When I try to store this line to a var result.document.getElementById("para1") I get and null variable. I can see it in the debug.

Comment: *Here's the HTML I used to determine the above*... if you've used the posted HTML for testing, you've missed a little thing: he calls the function from another site (index.html), there he opens a new window with an **<a>** in which the site containing the **p>#para1** element (PostEditor.html)... ergo there is no submit happening...